# How to get Processing to use a part of an array

Tags: processing

The software is for real-time analysis of an accelerometer chip. However it won't produce a graph using the array components. When I replace the dat[0/1/2] part in the void drawAxes with an actual number the graph is produced.

Is there any way to get the dat[] array to work in this system, or any alternatives I can use?
dat[]*100 is just to scale up the inserted value.

```
//Accelerometer graphing programme
//Author: Owain L. Evans, owainlevans@outlook.com
//Takes data from Arduino and produces a 3-Dimensional visualisation


import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort; //Serial Port
String DataLine; //Input from serial port

float[] dat;

PVector a = new PVector(100, 50, 20);

void setup()
  {
  size(1024, 720, P3D);
  strokeWeight(3);

  dat = new float[3];

  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (myPort.available() > 0)
    {DataLine = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    }
  if (DataLine != null) {
  println(DataLine);
  float dat[] = float(split(DataLine, ","));  //parse comma-separated number string into numbers
  println(dat);
  println();
  }
  background(250);
  drawAxes(dat[0]*100, dat[1]*100, dat[2]*100);  //draw original coordinate system
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  rotateX(map(mouseY,0,height,-PI,PI));
  rotateY(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));

  drawAxes(dat[0]*100, dat[1]*100, dat[2]*100);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(a.x, a.y, a.z);  //isolate coordinate system and draw translated A point
  popMatrix();
}

void drawAxes(float x, float y, float z) {
  //X - red
  stroke(192, 0, 0);  
  line( 0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0);
  //Y - green
  stroke(0, 192, 0);
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0);
  //Z - blue
  stroke(0, 0, 192);
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, z);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the dat array? A fix could be to store each value in a seperate value and start from there.

Comment: It would be good so see how the `dat` array is manipulated and perhaps a short snippet of data ?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the full code. Sorry in advance if it looks horrific, I'm a physics undergrad so coding isn't my strongest point. While it opens a window to draw in, there is nothing being drawn

Comment: @OwainL.Evans No worries about the code: we're all here to learn. It's now clear what you're trying to achieve: see updated answer. If still there's nothing being drawn double check what `println(dataLine)` outputs and ensure the data is valid and can be drawn in the viewport (nothing too small or too large to be renderered or overlapping data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell what's going on with the array, but you could add parameters to `drawAxes()` which would remove the tight coupling to `dat` and make it re-usable for other sketches:

```
void drawAxes(float x, float y, float z) {
  //X - red
  stroke(192, 0, 0);  
  line( 0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0);
  //Y - green
  stroke(0, 192, 0);
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0);
  //Z - blue
  stroke(0, 0, 192);
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, z);
}
```

(e.g. `drawAxes(dat[0] * 100, dat[1] * 100, dat[2] * 100);`)

**Update** I understand what you mean: you would like to build a graph of the incoming data and plot.

The issue is at the moment you are only storing a single sample which continuously gets updated.

To plot a graph with multiple values you would need to:

1. create an array to store multiple samples
2. update the array (shifting old values as a new one arrives)
3. iterate through the array and plot each value

**Step 1:** make an `[n-samples][3]` 2D array to store incoming data.
For the sake of argument let's store a history of 30 samples:

```
int sampleDimensions = 3;
// how many samples to record
int numSamples = 30;
// where to store the data
float[][] samples = new float[numSamples][sampleDimensions];
```

**Step 2:** Update the samples (shifting old ones, adding new data):

```
// read a new sample x,y,z entry and append it
void updateSamples(float x, float y, float z) {
  // shift oldest samples by 1: count backwards from oldest sample to 2nd sample
  for (int i = numSamples - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    // copy previous sample data: offsetting old data by 1
    samples[i][0] = samples[i-1][0];
    samples[i][1] = samples[i-1][1];
    samples[i][2] = samples[i-1][2];
  }
  // add newest entry as the first sample (replacing old data)
  samples[0][0] = x;
  samples[0][1] = y;
  samples[0][2] = z;
}
```

**Step 3** Iterate through the data and plot:

```
// render samples on screen with the option to scale the data
void drawSamples(float scale) {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < numSamples; i++){
    drawAxes(samples[i][0] * scale, samples[i][1] * scale, samples[i][2] * scale);
  }
}
```

Bare in mind this isn't super efficient in terms of rendering, however for 30 samples should be fine. In the end it's the legibility of the visualisation style that matters.

If you want to do a simpler to render visualisation you could simply render a line:

```
void drawSamples(float scale) {
  beginShape();
  for (int i = 0 ; i < numSamples; i++){
    vertex(samples[i][0] * scale, samples[i][1] * scale, samples[i][2] * scale);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

Putting the whole thing together:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort; //Serial Port
String dataLine; //Input from serial port

PVector a = new PVector(100, 50, 20);

int sampleDimensions = 3;
// how many samples to record
int numSamples = 30;
// where to store the data
float[][] samples = new float[numSamples][sampleDimensions];

// stores a single data sample from serial
float[] sample = new float[sampleDimensions]; 
// how much to scale data for visualisation
float sampleRenderScale = 100;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 720, P3D);
  strokeWeight(3);
  noFill();
  // try to open serial connection: display error otherwise (port missing, or busy (already open in Serial Monitor, etc.))
  try {
    String portName = Serial.list()[0];
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  }catch(Exception e) {
    println("error openin serial port: " + Serial.list()[0]);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}

void draw() {
  if(myPort != null){
    if (myPort.available() > 0){
      dataLine = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');

      if (dataLine != null) {
        println(dataLine);
        sample = float(split(dataLine, ","));  //parse comma-separated number string into numbers
        println(sample);
        if(sample == null || sample.length < 3){
           println("parsed less than the expected 3 values:");
           return;
        }
        println();
        // add new sample to the list of recorded samples
        updateSamples(sample[0], sample[1], sample[2]);
      }
    }
  }


  background(250);

  drawAxes(sample[0] * sampleRenderScale, sample[1] * sampleRenderScale, sample[2] * sampleRenderScale);  //draw original coordinate system

  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  rotateX(map(mouseY, 0, height, -PI, PI));
  rotateY(map(mouseX, 0, width, -PI, PI));

  drawAxes(sample[0] * sampleRenderScale, sample[1] * sampleRenderScale, sample[2] * sampleRenderScale);
  // draw recorded samples
  drawSamples(sampleRenderScale);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(a.x, a.y, a.z);  //isolate coordinate system and draw translated A point
  popMatrix();
}

// read a new sample x,y,z entry and append it
void updateSamples(float x, float y, float z) {
  // shift oldest samples by 1: count backwards from oldest sample to 2nd sample
  for (int i = numSamples - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    // copy previous sample data: offsetting old data by 1
    samples[i][0] = samples[i-1][0];
    samples[i][1] = samples[i-1][1];
    samples[i][2] = samples[i-1][2];
  }
  // add newest entry as the first sample (replacing old data)
  samples[0][0] = x;
  samples[0][1] = y;
  samples[0][2] = z;
}

// render samples on screen with the option to scale the data
void drawSamples(float scale) {
  beginShape();
  for (int i = 0 ; i < numSamples; i++){
    vertex(samples[i][0] * scale, samples[i][1] * scale, samples[i][2] * scale);
  }
  endShape();
}

void drawAxes(float x, float y, float z) {
  //X - red
  stroke(192, 0, 0); 
  line( 0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0); 
  //Y - green
  stroke(0, 192, 0); 
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0); 
  //Z - blue
  stroke(0, 0, 192); 
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, z);
}
```

Notice a few changes:

- `DataLine` renamed to `dataLine` (as per [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))
- generally renamed variables to it's easy to understand what they are/do and formatting the code so it's easier to read
- error handling serial port connection. You already did error handling for incoming data which is great.

The idea is to build good habbits as you progress.

If you have time to explore other languages I recommend Python and few modules,
potentially to start cluserting/classifying the sensor data if that's of interest:

- [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for serial communication
- [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/): `numpy` for fast array manipulation, [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/rotate_axes3d.html) for plotting and [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for classiciation/clustering/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however it's now saying there is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on line 45. Depending on which exception value it throws back (either 1 or 2), it sometimes starts to draw something, but obviously stops upon the error, any advice on how to rectify this?

Comment: The fact that issue is intermittend points to potentially incorrect data from Serial. Does `println(sample);` always print an array of 3 values (or is it sometimes < 3) ? See the updated check if sample is not and has at least 3 values. Hopefully that will keep resolve the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. What that likely means is that you're trying to access `sample[0],sample[1],sample[2]` and either sample is `null` or doesn't have 3 elements.

Comment: Sending a long string of characters over serial with a single terminator is an easy way to send multiple values, however if anything goes wrong with the serial communication at any point it's likely bytes won't arrive as reliably hence malformed serial data: this means the checks on the parsing side need to be very strict. If the answer as helpful feel free to vote up and mark it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it